# How to create a SimpleDate from ayear String in Java

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, date

I have a set of strings. This strings are actually "year"s. for example: `"1967"`,`"1872"`,`"2012"`,...

I want to create a SimpleDate instance from each of these. Is there a way to create a SimpleDate from a year String?

I have a rather hacky solution for this, which is attaching `"-00-00"` to my year strings and parsing it into a a SimpleDate. I need a more non-hacky way of doing this.
Thx

Comment: What's a `SimpleDate`?. What library are you using?

Comment: What do you need as Month & Date ?

Comment: I have a piece of code in another place which gets a date as a string. and parses it using SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"). I don't want to touch this part of code. I just want to turn that year string in a proper date format that can be used in this piece of code.

Comment: @Hossein In your question you are talking about `SimpleDate`, which does not exist. I guess you want a `Date` and you had a confusion with `SimpleDateFormat`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe you asking about something like this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat();
sdf.applyPattern("YYYY");
Date d=null;
try {
    d = sdf.parse("1999");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(year), 0, 1);          
    calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
String str_date="1997";
Date date;
try {
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
  date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
} catch (ParseException e) { 
  // handle exception (date will be null)
}
```